# Ibm Mobile First No More Direct Updates

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst

Im getting this warning / message sometimes when I deploy my app to the server:

> FWLSE3210W: Environment: ipad of application MyApp version 1.0 has
>   been deployed with a different version of the native MobileFirst SDK.
>   Direct updates will no longer be available for existing clients with
>   other versions of the MobileFirst SDK. To continue to use direct
>   updates, increment the app version, publish it to the public app
>   store, deploy to the server, and (optionally) block/notify older
>   versions of the app to enforce customers to upgrade to the new version
>   from the app store.

Whenever I get this message, the direct updates no longer be available for the existing devices that I previously deploy.

Solution I have taken,

1. Update / Increment the app version:

I updated my iPad app version from 1.0 to 1.1 at application-descriptor.xml and then deploy again to the server.

2. Block Older Version:

I have also lock the older version at the Mobile First Console Site.

The only step that have not been taken is "publish it to the public app store" , but as we are in development mode, there isn't any public app store.

I also notice that this issue usually happens when there are native code changes.

Answer (score 0):

You are doing exactly what you should be doing. Some iFixes may contain changes to the native layer of the client SDK, and so a Studio build containing this will detect that your current project/app will lack these unless you re-build and re-submit your app to the app stores.

What you've listed are the steps you should be following when that warning is displayed.

Comment: hi @idan so what you are saying the only solution that i should apply is "re-build and re-submit your app to the app stores" and by app store means apple app store?

Comment: As I am in development / testing environment now, I did not submit my app to store. Is there any other solutions?

Comment: re-build the app...?

Comment: Re-build the app and deploy to my server? Yes, i have done that.

Comment: Hi @Idan any solutions?

Comment: I don't understand the problem... if you're during development and you upgrade to a newer studio build and you get this message, then you need to follow your own suggestions... if you're not using any custom native code in your hybrid app you can also delete the /native folder and rebuild.

Comment: Hi @Idan , the issue is that I did the steps mention(the steps in the question) and the devices still could not get the direct updates that they use to get. I'm also having some custom native code in my  hybrid app so i could not delete the native folder.